# Save canvas as png

Tags: javascript, canvas, save

I need help with saving canvas as png. It is being saved as a file without extension

Using canvas2image library
http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/

```
$(function() { 
    $("#dlbutton").click(function() { 
        html2canvas($("#canvas"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                theCanvas = canvas;
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);

                // Convert and download as image 
                Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas); 
                $("#img-out").append(canvas);
                // Clean up 
                //document.body.removeChild(canvas);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/JCQm5/7**

what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using Canvas2Image from http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/, this library works only on canvas elements.

Did you add the needed base64, and canvas2image js files to a script tag in the head section?
Is onrendered really triggered?

Comment: Check fiddle extensions. They are there.(External resources on the left)

Comment: I suggest you get the serialized data for the image and use https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/ which let's you choose the filename.